# Extract part of a text and split into two columns

Tags: python, pandas, python-re

I am trying to extract some part of the following sentences (I have similar rows following similar pattern):

```
Text
19 hours ago — Catch up on key developments an...
8 hour ago — Catch up on key developments an...
10 minutes ago — Catch up on key developments an...
1 day ago — Catch up on key developments an...
```

I would like to split the Text column into two. (before and after the —) :

```
Text1          Text 2
19 hours ago   Catch up on key developments an...
8 hour ago     Catch up on key developments an...
10 minutes ago Catch up on key developments an...
1 day ago      Catch up on key developments an...
```

I did this:

```
df[['Text1', 'Text2']] = df['Text'].str.extract(r"(\d+ \w+, \d{5})?\s*\—?\s*(.*)", expand=True)
```

However it seems not working.
If you have experience with `re`, could you please point me to the mistake and to the solution? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`pandas.Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html#pandas-series-str-split) function:

```
df['Text'].str.split(' — ', n=1, expand=True)
```

You need `n=1` to limit the number of splits in output. Also, you need to set `expand=True` to use the expanding functionality.

Comment: +1 for adding the `n` parameter since the text will most likely, at some point, contain more than one "-" symbols.

Comment: Yes, n=1 plays a crucial role, good answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use split rather than Regex.

```
df[['Text1', 'Text2']] = df['Text'].str.split('-',n=1,expand=True)
```

Output:

```
Text1          Text 2
19 hours ago   Catch up on key developments an...
8 hour ago     Catch up on key developments an...
10 minutes ago Catch up on key developments an...
1 day ago      Catch up on key developments an...
```